# Get return value IDENT_CURRENT from SQL Server in ADO.NET & C#

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I am using SQL Server 2014 and I have a stored procedure that returns a `int` value:

```
@ShippingDataID = IDENT_CURRENT ('ShippingData');
```

If I query the sql its work and I see the return value but in C# ADO.NET I always get NULL. I try few things that I see here but nothing works, I be happy for help.

This is my C# code:

```
using (con)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.spSetShippingData", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    SqlParameter tvpParam = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tvpNewShippingData", dt);
    tvpParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ShippingDataID", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    val = (int)cmd.Parameters["@ShippingDataID"].Value;

    returnValue = new SqlParameter();
    returnValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(returnValue);

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ShippingDataID", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    val = (int)cmd.Parameters["@ShippingDataID"].Value;
    //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

con.Close();
```

This is my SQL code:

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spSetShippingData] 
      @tvpNewShippingData dbo.TVPShippingDataTableType readonly
 AS
 BEGIN
     DECLARE @ShippingDataID INT = 0;

     INSERT INTO dbo.ShippingData(FirstName, LastName, Email, Phone, AdditionalPhone, City, Street, StreetNumber, Entrance, ApartmentNumber, PostalCode, CompanyID)
        SELECT 
            FirstName, LastName, Email, Phone, AdditionalPhone, 
            City, Street, StreetNumber, Entrance, 
            ApartmentNumber, PostalCode, CompanyID
        FROM 
            @tvpNewShippingData

    SET @ShippingDataID = IDENT_CURRENT ('ShippingData');

    SELECT @ShippingDataID;
END
```

Comment: Can you add the code of the stored procedure? In particular the declaration of the parameters and how do you set the return value?

Comment: i added the sql code.

Comment: `IDENT_CURRENT` is almost always the wrong function to use. Have you *deliberately* chosen to use it for some reason, rather than `SCOPE_IDENTITY`?

Comment: The issue is: you're returning the `ID` using a `SELECT` - so this will be a **result set** from the stored procedure. In your C# code, however, you're trying to read out a (non-existing?) output parameter..... you'll need to call your stored procedure with `ExecuteScalar()` from C# and read out that value from the result set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to receive the value of IDENT_CURRENT via a return parameter (not via an out parameter) then you need to call the RETURN statement inside the stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spSetShippingData] @tvpNewShippingData 
    dbo.TVPShippingDataTableType readonly
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO dbo.ShippingData
        (FirstName,LastName,Email,Phone,AdditionalPhone,City,
        Street,StreetNumber,Entrance,ApartmentNumber,PostalCode,CompanyID)
    SELECT FirstName,LastName,Email,Phone,AdditionalPhone,City,
        Street,StreetNumber,Entrance,ApartmentNumber,PostalCode,CompanyID
    FROM @tvpNewShippingData
    RETURN IDENT_CURRENT ('ShippingData');
END
```

And now your C# code should receive the return value in a ReturnValue parameter

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ShippingDataID", SqlDbType.Int).Direction =    ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
val = (int)cmd.Parameters["@ShippingDataID"].Value;
```

Said that however I would prefer a simpler approach

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spSetShippingData] @tvpNewShippingData 
    dbo.TVPShippingDataTableType readonly
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO dbo.ShippingData
        (FirstName,LastName,Email,Phone,AdditionalPhone,City,
        Street,StreetNumber,Entrance,ApartmentNumber,PostalCode,CompanyID)
    SELECT FirstName,LastName,Email,Phone,AdditionalPhone,City,
        Street,StreetNumber,Entrance,ApartmentNumber,PostalCode,CompanyID
    FROM @tvpNewShippingData
    SELECT IDENT_CURRENT ('ShippingData');
END
```

And in your C# call ExecuteScalar instead of ExecuteNonQuery without using a return value

```
object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
int val = (result == null ? (int)0 : Convert.ToInt32(result);
```

ExecuteScalar will return the first column of the first row of the last SELECT executed by your code, so you don't need to build a parameter.

Comment: This is a good answer, I would just like to note that Return values are not intended for data, but for result codes. Also OUTPUT parameter would be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can add at the end of the procedure

```
SET @ShippingDataID = IDENT_CURRENT ('ShippingData'); 
SELECT @ShippingDataID AS RETURN_ID
```

And in c#

You can get value using DataAdapter

```
SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
adp.Fill(dt);
int shipingId =Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["RETURN_ID"].ToString());
```

i hope you can get some idea with this code.

Comment: You can use SET @ShippingDataID = (SELECT MAX(YourShippingDataId) from ShippingData)

Comment: in sql i see the return value but in c# i still get null.